# Parse contents of directory to bash command in a script

Tags: bash

I have the directory `~/fooscripts/` and inside there are `foo1.txt`, `foo2.txt`, etc etc

I have a command that takes the file `foo1.txt` as input and does some calculation. The output location etc  is handled internally in fooprog

```
fooprog -user-data=foo1.txt
```

I would like to automate the whole thing in a bash script so that the script will parse all txt files in `~/fooscripts/` sequentially. I am a newbie in bash. Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `for` loop and globbing to get the list of files:

```
for data in ~/fooscripts/foo*.txt ; do
    fooprog -user-data="$data"
done
```